# Displaytag export file is saving without extension

Tags: export, displaytag

The file name only coming when saving the exported file, how can we have the .xls or .pdf to come by default when an excel or pdf on saving the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the displaytag you can use the "export.excel.filename" property.

```
<display:setProperty name="export.excel.filename" value="file_name.xls"/>
```